# valid jq in angular, ether angular.element("#n") or $("#n")

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference?

```
angular.element("#n"); vs $("#n");
```

Sometimes better to use short code like 
`$compile($(".iComp"+iComp))($scope);`

Do I need to use `angular.element("#n")` strictly or not? for the right tone

Comment: AFAIK if you include jQuery before angular `$` and `angular.element` will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides a compact set of `jquery API` as `jqlite`, which is by default available in angular itself. If you are going to use the basic jquery funtions, then you can survive with `jqlite` provided by angular.
But if you are loading `jquery` script also, then you can use whichever you want.
Read more about it here: [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

If you are including jquery then no need to strictly use angular.element('#n'). But if you are not externally loading jquery, then you will have to use angular.element('#n') strictly.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, then you can mark it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

`Angular.element` falls back to the `jqLite` library if `jQuery` is not loaded, this is a slimmer version of `jQuery`. [More info about `jqLite` here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)